# Print top 3 scores and bottom 3 scores in a file

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

```
#Name,Scores
a,6
b,8
c,2
k,23
d,18
r,13
w,4
h,9
```

The code should print the Name and Scores of the top 3 bands in order (starting with top, to bottom).

The code should then print the Name and Scores of the bottom 3 bands in order (starting with bottom, to top).

How do I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your attempt in solving the problem ?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions and https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/5386938

Comment: @JustinEzequiel The second link was really helpful,

Comment: @Daniel kindly vote up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert it into dictionary, then sort the dictionary and then print top and bottom bands.

```
team = {'a': 6, 'b': 8, 'c': 2, 'k': 23, 'd': 18, 'r': 13, 'w': 4, 'h': 9}

team = sorted(team.items(), key =
             lambda kv:(kv[1], kv[0]), reverse=True)
print(team)
print("Top 3 Bands")
print(team[:3])
print("Bottom 3 Bands")
print(team[-3:])
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for responding,

Comment: What does kv and reverse = True do?

Comment: `Kv` is an argument of lambda which is using to sort the dictionary according to their key. And `reverse=True` means it will sort the dictionary in an ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

You should make them variables and store the values into the variables, then use a `while True:` line and add a line that compares one variable with another, then use `print()` to print all the top 3 first then `print()` the bottom 3.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
with open ('data.txt') as f:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
  lines = [tuple(l.split(',')) for l in lines]
  lines.sort(key=lambda tup: int(tup[1]))
  print(lines[:3])
  lines[-3:].reverse()
  print(lines[-3:])
```

where data.txt is

```
a,6
b,8
c,2
k,23
d,18
r,13
w,4
h,9
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. What does strip do?

Comment: Strip will remove all the blank spaces from the string. Just like '/n'.

Comment: @Daniel . If my answer helped you, fell free to vote up.

Answer (score 1):

> You Can use list of tuples and use slicing to obtain the results

```
lt = [('a',6),
('b',8),
('c',2),
('k',23),
('d',18),
('r',13),
('w',4),
('h',9)]

print(lt[:3]) #for first three
print(lt[-3:]) #for last three
```